# Eclipse: How to retrieve a resource from a bundle

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I am using this code to retrieve a folder from a bundle

```
URL url = Platform.getBundle("myBundle").getEntry("myFolder");
File fileTmp = null;
try {
     fileTmp = new File(FileLocator.resolve(url).toURI());
} catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e1.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is that although it works if I run it as an Eclipse Application, it does not if i export it in the dropins folder and restart Eclipse. In this case it seems the FileLocator fails to resolve the url.
Am i missing something?

**UPDATE**
I have opened the jar of the exported plugin and I can't actually find the folder I am trying to retrieve. There has to be something that I should configure before to export the plugin in order to export the folder as well. How can I do that?

See this: [Eclipse: how to export a folder in a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420698/eclipse-how-to-export-a-folder-in-a-plugin)

Comment: how does it fail? Do you have a stacktrace of exception?

Comment: a small dialog with a red cross popup with no message inside. I tried to start Eclipse from shell but nothing seems to be printed out in the console.

Comment: Try to log the url variable and the result of FileLocator.resolve(url)

Comment: try to restart your app with -consoleLog flag, and following VM flags: 
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -Dequinox.ds.debug=true
-Dequinox.ds.print=true

Comment: Platform.getBundle(..) returns null when the plugin is loaded from the dropin folder while works fine when the plugin is run as an Eclipse Application

Comment: Maybe problem with symbolic name.. call getBundles() from your BundleContext and log out all bundle.getSymbolicName(). Does it present there?

Comment: If this will not help, please see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox%5Fp2%5FGetting%5FStarted#Debugging_dropins

Comment: I have printed the bundles through the bundle context. The bundle I am looking for is present with the name I am using. May the problem be related to the fact the object which is trying to get the bundle belongs to it? If so is there any different way to get the current bundle?

Comment: Is your code in the same bundle as you want to get the resource from? If yes you can use the classloader of your class to get the URL: ClassInTheSameBundle.class.getResource...

Answer (score 0):

Instead `Platform`, try to get the resource via your `AbstractUIPlugin` implementation (if you have one), for example: `Application.getDefault().getBundle().getResource(name)`