# Eclipse: how to export a folder in a plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I have a plugin containing a folder with files the plugin uses. 
I have noticed the folder is not exported in the plugin jar during its export.
I guess there has to be some configuration I am missing but I can't find where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to MANIFEST.MF editor and in the `Build` tab you need to add the directory to the `"Binary Build"`

(This is the Gui way of what Michal Borek said. Both will have the same result)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this folders to `build.properties` file in `bin.includes` section.